# Angular how to go to a particular part of page upon clicking the link

Tags: angular

This is the Template code or html code of the angular faq page upon clicking the above links(see image for refernce ) i want the to scroll down to certain section of the page for which the link is given please help me how to do this!!!

```
<div id="wrap-content-v1" class="wrap-content">
<div class="main">
    <div>
        <div id="summary">
            <span [innerHTML]="'tk.faq.summaryPageTitle' | translateHTML" id="faq_title" class="faq_title">
            </span><br>
            <span [innerHTML]="'tk.faq.summaryPageSubtitle' | translateHTML" id="faq_subtitle" class="faq_subtitle">
            </span>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="faqSummaryList{{faqSection.rank}}"
                *ngFor="let faqSection of faqSectionlist.FAQContentDisplayBean.faqSectionList">


                <div *ngIf="faqSection.summaryTitle!==null && faqSection.summaryTitle.length>0"
                    class="faq_textBullet" id="faqSummaryDisplay{{faqSection.rank}}">
                    <a (click)="gotoPagedivwithRank('faqSection.rank')" class="faq_summaryTitle"
                        id="faqSummary{{faqSection.rank}}" onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;">
                        <span id="faqSummaryValue{{faqSection.rank}}">{{faqSection.summaryTitle}}</span></a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div *ngFor="let faqSection of faqSectionlist.FAQContentDisplayBean.faqSectionList">
            <div *ngFor="let faqSubsection of faqSection.faqSubsectionList">
                <ng-container [ngSwitch]="faqSubsection.type">
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Title'" id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Title">
                        <span class="faq_title" id="faq_subtitle">{{faqSubsection.text}}
                        </span><br> <br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Subtitle'" id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Subtitle">
                        <span class="faq_subtitle" id="faq_subtitle">{{faqSubsection.text}}
                        </span><br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text'" id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Text">
                        <span class="faq_text" id="faq_text">{{faqSubsection.text}}</span><br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'TextWithBullet'"
                        id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_TextWithBullet">
                        <span class="faq_textBullet" id="faq_textBullet"><span class="faq_textWithBullet"
                                id="faq_textWithBullet">{{faqSubsection.text}}</span></span>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Image'" id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Image">
                        <img src="faqSubsection.image" alt="image" class="faq_image" id="faq_image" /><br>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Link' && identifyLink(faqSubsection.linkURL)"
                        id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_ExternalLink" class="faq_link">
                        <a href="{{faqSubsection.linkURL}}" id="faq_external_link"><span class="faq_link"
                                id="faq_link">{{faqSubsection.text}}</span></a><br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Link' && identifyLink(faqSubsection.linkURL)!==null"
                        id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_InternalLink" class="faq_link">
                        <a id="gotoPageDivWithURL" (click)="gotoPageDivWithURL(faqSubsection.linkURL)"
                            onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"><span class="faq_link"
                                id="faq_link">{{faqSubsection.text}}</span></a><br>
                    </div>
                    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Item'" id="faq{{faqSection.rank}}_{{faqSubsection.rank}}_Item">
                        <span class="faq_itemBullet" id="faq_itemBullet"><span class="faq_item"
                                id="faq_item">{{faqSubsection.text}}</span></span>
                    </div>
                </ng-container>
            </div>
            <br><br> <a (click)="gotoPageDiv()" class="goToHomeFAQ" id="goToHomeFAQ{{faqSection.rank}}"
                onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;"></a><br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the component of the the template:

```
 import { Location, ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
 import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { FaqResponse } from '@models/faq/faqResponse';
 import { FaqService } from '@myse/faq/faq.service';
 import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

 @Component({
    providers: [Location],
    selector: 'myse-faq',
    styleUrls: ['./faq.component.scss'],
    templateUrl: './faq.component.html'
  })
 export class FaqComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   faqSectionlist: FaqResponse;
   subscription: Subscription;

 gotoPageWithRank: any;
 gotoPagedivWithRank: any;
 identifylink: any;
 rank: any;
 divName: any;

constructor(
  private readonly faqservice: FaqService,
  private readonly router: Router,
  private readonly route: ActivatedRoute,
  private readonly viewportScroller: ViewportScroller
) { }

async ngOnInit() {
  this.faqSectionlist = await this.faqservice.getFaqContent();

}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

gotoPageDiv() {

  window.scroll({
   behavior: 'auto',
   left: 0,
   top: 0
 });

}

 gotoPagedivwithRank(elementId: any): void {
 this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(elementId);

}
gotoPageDivWithURL(url) {
  this.divName = String(url);
}

 identifyLink(link) {
   if (link == null) {
   this.identifylink = null;
   return this.identifyLink;
  } else {
  if (link.substring(0, 3) === 'faq') {
     this.rank = link.substring(3);
     } else {
     this.identifylink = null;
     return this.identifylink;
   }
 }
  }
}
```

THIS IS THE OUTPUT IMAGE I WANT THESE ABOVE LINKS TO GET DIRECTED TO CERTAIN PART OF PAGE BELOW

[The Link part of the page from which certain part of the page will be directed to if clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdnJt.png)

[The page is divided in ranks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoDW2.png)

Comment: Why not just use a simple [anchor tag](https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/responsive-web-design/basic-html-and-html5/link-to-internal-sections-of-a-page-with-anchor-elements): `<a href="#my_id"...>`?

Comment: i want to scroll down certain sections of page based on the links which is in ngFor